# SwiftUI: DatePicker is it possible to display date/time in other timezone then current?

Tags: datepicker, swiftui, uidatepicker

In UIDatePicker we can do something like this

```
datePicker.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 5*60*60)
```

in order to specify timezone of datepicker.

But how about doing this in DatePicker in SwiftUI, I cannot find any such param or modifier.

Comment: you can create UIDatepicker using UIViewRepresentable

Comment: yea but I think swiftui support this also

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is possible to do with SwiftUI `.environment` modifier as in below example

```
DatePicker("Due Date", selection: $selected,
    displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute]
)
.environment(\.timeZone, TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 5*60*60)!)
```

Comment: Do you know where I can find full list of this environment keywords available for different controls or accessible via @Environment?

Comment: In SwiftUI module (Cmd-Click on it in import line and Jump to Definition) and look for `EnvironmentValues` declarations.

Comment: I was about to build my own custom DatePicker from scratch and this answer just saved me *hours* of work. Thank you.

Comment: This seems to work at first sight, but if you enter a value at another than the first position, the selection jumps to the first position. I don't know whether this is a new bug or did never really work. This is the exact code:
`struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selected: Date = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DatePicker("Due Date", selection: $selected,
                displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute]
            )
            .environment(\.timeZone, TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 5*60*60)!)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}`